# Why is the question off-topic?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, question-closure

I can see that users are voting to close the question [Where does Martian meaning inhabitant of Mars come from?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/559819/where-does-martian-meaning-inhabitant-of-mars-come-from) as off-topic.

What’s  the problem with the above question? or is it just a question of grumpy users as a commenter has suggested?

Comment: Which close reason did the close voters choose? Did they say “I’m closing this question because I’m grumpy” or did they choose a more constructive reason?

Comment: @ColleenV - that’s what I’d like to know. Why do they think the question is off-topic? In what way is my question not respectful of  the site standards.?

Comment: When people vote to close a question, they have to provide a reason they're voting to close. I can't see it because I don't have enough reputation, but you should be able to see it as the questions author, shouldn't you?

Comment: There are 3 pending close votes, all of them for “Needs more research...”. Which is basically our default close reason. I’m not one of the downvotes but if I had to speculate, it’s based on reading the title but not the body, or not the body closely enough. From the tittle I would have assumed it was questioning the relationship between “Martian” and “Mars” which would be “too basic”. But from the body you’re looking for first or early usages of Martian for natives of Mars, beyond dictionary cites, which is a service we are used to providing here (c.f. Sven Yargs).

Comment: @ColleenV, when people vote to close a question, they do **not** have to provide the reason they're voting to close. The only thing they have to do is select one item from the menu of pre-fabricated reasons. Often none of the items on that menu captures the actual reason, so people choose whichever one seems to be the closest, even if it is not very close. The posted reasons for closing thus tend not to be very informative to those whose questions are closed, and are sometimes positively misleading.

Comment: @jsw29 - what do you mean by “positively misleading”?

Comment: @jsw29 I understand that, I was asking if the close voters hadn't provided some clues with their close votes. I was trying to gather more information, not discount the question.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - the question was probably a bit unclear  and I should have offered  more evidence of research. I’ll look into it and make a better one.

Comment: Just saw what happened. Little wonder that users are turned off by the "experts". The Q was valid, regardless if someone says that the answer is "nobody knows".

Comment: What happened? Why did you delete [a well-received, and upvoted answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/602926/44619)? I don't remember seeing any comments criticising your post. There are no downvotes. Is it the edit? You can totally rollback.

Answer (score 5):

Close votes happen, even on etymology questions that show research, which are arguably some of the most on-topic questions for this site. [That’s nothing new,](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11824/191178) though in this case I really have no guess as to why, not with the specific close reason given.

(You could have written an online etymology dictionary and you would still have gotten 3 close votes on your etymology question.)

Either way, if the question gets closed, you have my reopen vote. (I’m sure I’m not the only one.)